# Can I change the user that runs a java Elastic Beanstalk app

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm successfully running a Java app in Elastic Beanstalk.

Is there anyway I can control the ID of the user that starts the app? It looks like it by default it's running as user webapp - I have no idea if the user/group IDs are static or could change in future.

Thanks in advance,

SP

Comment: What problem is the current user causing you? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The process needs to pick up files from EFS - I need to ensure the service has permission to consume these files.

I assume it would be easiest to ensure that the process that adds the file has the same user ID as the consuming service.

Therefore I'd need some guarantee this user ID would stay the same across any newly deployed instances of the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) to permit instances to copy files from EFS. There's some EFS specific information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/access-control-managing-permissions.html). In general IAM roles are the best way to give EC2 instances access to other AWS services.

In this case you would probably have one EFS share set up for this specific purpose. Anyone who has access to the share can access any file on the share. If you need more fine grained permissions then you could look at whether IAM allows this or you have to find another technique.